# How to use rust async_trait generic to a lifetime parameter?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, traits, lifetime

I'm trying to make an `async_trait` where some implementations are generic to types with lifetime parameters:

```
use async_trait::async_trait;

struct MyLifetimeType<'a> {
  s: &'a mut String,
}

#[async_trait]
trait MyTrait<T> {
  async fn handle(t: T);
}

struct MyImpl;

#[async_trait]
impl<'a> MyTrait<MyLifetimeType<'a>> for MyImpl {
  async fn handle(t: MyLifetimeType<'a>) {
    t.s.push_str("hi");
  }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get

```
error[E0276]: impl has stricter requirements than trait
  --> ...
   |
18 |   async fn handle(t: T);
   |   ---------------------- definition of `handle` from trait
...
25 |   async fn handle(t: MyLifetimeType<'a>) {
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ impl has extra requirement `'a: 'async_trait`
```

It seems that the issue is related to `async_trait` somehow using the lifetime parameter `'a` under the hood. When I get rid of all the `async` and `async_trait`, the code compiles fine. How can I avoid this `extra requirement` error?

For more context, to explain why have handlers implementing `MyTrait` that can operate on structs containing mutable pointers: I have a function that obtains `RwLockReadGuard`s and `RwLockWriteGuard`s for a couple different locks, then passes the contents to a handler. For the write guards, I need some way for the handler to mutate contents, so I pass a mutable pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/dtolnay/async-trait/issues/8#issuecomment-514812245). The author recommends adding an explicit lifetime bound when that error occurs:

```rust
use async_trait::async_trait;

struct MyLifetimeType<'a> {
  s: &'a mut String,
}

#[async_trait]
trait MyTrait<T> {
  async fn handle(&self, t: T) where T: 'async_trait;
}

struct MyImpl;

#[async_trait]
impl<'a> MyTrait<MyLifetimeType<'a>> for MyImpl {

  async fn handle(&self, t: MyLifetimeType<'a>) {
    t.s.push_str("hi");
  }
  
}
```